# Structuring scorm package with just one item

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I recently packaged a Scorm course, and everything looks ok, but when they launch the course they have to click first in one menu button from the LMS, and open a submenu and they have to click again, in other courses they just click in the parent item. I think it's something to do with the structure in the Manifest file, the thing is that I have just one item so the menu is not really necesary.

This is what my client sees:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<!--
Single SCO content packaging example. SCORM 2004 2nd Edition.

Provided by Rustici Software - http://www.scorm.com

This example demonstrates the simplest possible manifest, containing just one SCO and 
no metdata or sequencing information.
-->

<!-- 
The manifest node contains a unique identifer for this course and the course's version number.
The schema declartions are important to ensure you are delivering valid XML. For the most part
these should remain static. Other schema prefixes are allowed, but can limit interoperabilty.
-->
<manifest identifier="com.scorm.golfsamples.contentpackaging.singlesco.20042nd" version="1"
              xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"
              xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3"
              xmlns:adlseq="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlseq_v1p3"
              xmlns:adlnav="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlnav_v1p3"
              xmlns:imsss="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1 imscp_v1p1.xsd
                            http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3 adlcp_v1p3.xsd
                            http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlseq_v1p3 adlseq_v1p3.xsd
                            http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlnav_v1p3 adlnav_v1p3.xsd
                            http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss imsss_v1p0.xsd">

  <!--The metadata node simply declares which SCORM version this course operates under.
  "CAM 1.3" is the notation for SCORM 2004 2nd Edition.-->
  <metadata>
    <schema>ADL SCORM</schema>
    <schemaversion>CAM 1.3</schemaversion>
  </metadata>
  <!-- There is just one organization. The organization contains just one item.-->
  <organizations default="control_interno" adlseq:objectivesGlobalToSystem="false">
    <organization identifier="control_interno">
      <title>Control Interno</title>
      <item identifier="item_1" identifierref="resource_1">
        <title>Control Interno</title>
      </item>
      <imsss:sequencing>
        <imsss:controlMode choice="true" flow="true" />
      </imsss:sequencing>
    </organization>
  </organizations>
  <!-- 
  There is just one resource that represents the single SCO that comprises the entirety of this course.
  The href attribute points to the launch URL for the course and all of the files required by the course
  are listed.
  -->
  <resources>
    <resource identifier="resource_1" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormType="sco" href="./control_interno/index.html">
      <file href="./control_interno/index.html"/>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Something similar happened to me while I was testing my scorm package.

Comment: Yep, this is someting that is controlled by the backend, in my case CornerStone, so you have to deactivate that menu from there. The other option is to use Scorm version 1.2, because that menu isn't compatible there, hope I could help